# Unity upgrade to 2022.3 or Gradle Upgrade to 7x Causing Black Screen (GetGpuPixelFormat Error)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, graphics, textures

I've had to upgrade to Unity 2022.3, which comes with the Gradle plugin upgrade from 4.0.1 to 7.1.2 and gradle from 6x to 7x. android.enableR8 had to be removed from gradle.properties, since it is apparently now always on.

However now I am getting a black screen (not a lethal crash) after the splash art displays. Logcat is giving the following error:

```
Error qdgralloc GetGpuPixelFormat: No map for format: 0x38
Error AdrenoUtils <validate_memory_layout_input_parmas:1923>: Unknown Format 0
Error AdrenoUtils <adreno_init_memory_layout:4634>: Memory Layout input parameter validation failed!
Error qdgralloc GetGpuResourceSizeAndDimensions Graphics metadata init failed
Error Gralloc4 isSupported(1, 1, 56, 1, ...) failed with 1
Error GraphicBufferAllocator Failed to allocate (4 x 4) layerCount 1 format 56 usage b00: 1
Error AHardwareBuffer GraphicBuffer(w=4, h=4, lc=1) failed (Unknown error -1), handle=0x0
```

I've found this documentation which contains the pixelformat code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/PixelFormat.java

which includes the following line:

```
public static final int R_8 = 0x38;
```

which is the closest thing I've found to a clue regarding the GetGpuPixelFormat error. Which leads me to think the issue is somehow related to R8?

What I've so far tried is disabling Vulkan and resetting graphics settings in Unity, sadly to no avail. A new project doesn't have any issue, but when I copy my assets from the main project (including the Gradle files), the issue starts again.

I am mainly a Unity user and not experienced in Android development.

Edit: Should also mention that iOS Build works fine on the Iphone.

Edit2: While building a new project and adding my assets one by one, I've realized that some of my scenes actually load some textures and don't load others, some scenes don't load any textures. Could not yet determine what those who don't load have in common. It almost seems random. Except that all textures that don't load seem to be part of the UI.

Comment: R8 in Gradle is a code minimizer and optimizer, it doesn't have anything to do with what you showed in the source code. https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code I'd check to make sure you have all of your shaders in the build and also make sure you're not using any weird texture compression settings. Since adding your assets to a working project breaks it you may have to be more surgical about it. Add them in stages testing each stage and see when it breaks then try and narrow down what part of what you added is causing the issue.

Comment: You might also try things like adjusting engine stripping settings. Annoying problem, I hope you're able to figure it out or someone else that had the problem and fixed it shares some insight.

Comment: I will try all that, thank you. I've also realized that this R8 has nothing to do with enableR8 but is a pixel format. Just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

So this wasn't about textures. My UI elements were being pushed out of the screen space because of the Safe Area script that I was using. I can't discern what caused this, but Canvas.pixelRect was returning totally wrong values on Android. Not in editor simulator, not on iOS, but only on Android phones. The issue is new, since the script I am using for safe area adjustment I've been using for years without issue.

I tried waiting for one frame before taking the pixelRect, and this solved the issue. The resolutions given were correct.